# will a package be packaged by webpack if it is in npm dependencies but never be used

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, webpack

For example, I install a package A with `npm i A -s`, but it never be used in the project, will it be packaged after execute `webpack`?

Answer (score 1):

No. If you don’t `require` or `import` it from somewhere it’s not included.